# Is it possible to make a custom map in Google Maps API v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm working on a personal project involving map-making tools for a tabletop game that I play. I've worked with Google Maps in the past before, and it looks like in version 3 of the API, they have removed the API key restriction.

I have done some research into making a custom map, and have come across [this page on mapki](http://mapki.com/wiki/Add_Your_Own_Custom_Map), but the example seems to be focussed on creating new tiles for existing real-world coordinates.

Is it possible to make custom maps that are not dependent on real-world coordinates in the Google Maps API v3?

(Slight tangent: If it is not possible to do this, what other tools exist to make custom maps?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/). I get the impression it's used a lot in the OpenStreetMaps community.

> OpenLayers makes it easy to put a
>   dynamic map in any web page. It can
>   display map tiles and markers loaded
>   from any source. OpenLayers has been
>   developed to further the use of
>   geographic information of all kinds.
>   OpenLayers is completely free, Open
>   Source JavaScript, released under the
>   2-clause BSD License (also known as
>   the FreeBSD).

You could use [Mapnik](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mapnik) to render the tiles and serve them yourself. The OSM wiki has lots of documentation on doing that sort of thing.